# Correct implementation of UserPassesTestMixin or AccessMixin in class based view

Tags: django, django-views

When using class-based views, you can use the `UserPassesTestMixin` in the following way ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class MyView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.email.endswith('@example.com')
```

The docs also state:

> Furthermore, you can set any of the parameters of AccessMixin to customize the handling of unauthorized users

However, no example of the syntax is provided as to how to do this. For example, how would I set `raise_exception` and `permission_denied_message` so authenticated users get an exception error and not a 403?

This does not work, as users are still returned a 403 error:

```
class MyView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    raise_exception = True
    permission_denied_message = 'You have been denied'


    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.email.endswith('@example.com')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should override the `handle_no_permission` method to handle what the user sees when it does not pass the test:

```
class MyView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.email.endswith('@example.com')

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        """ Do whatever you want here if the user doesn't pass the test """
        return HttpResponse('You have been denied')
```

Answer (score 0):

Class-based view `UserPassesTestMixin` inherited from the `AccessMixin` mixin which has denoted options. From the documentation of [raise_exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.raise_exception).

> If this attribute is set to `True`, a PermissionDenied exception is
>   raised when the conditions are not met. When False (the default),
>   anonymous users are redirected to the login page.

As you set it to True and a user wasn't authenticated the 403 status would be returned by the server. Option `permission_denied_message` only controls the message that would be passed to the PermissionDenied exception. It does not return any messages to a user (of course you can override it). A little bit simplified version from the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py#L7):

```
def handle_no_permission(self):
    if self.raise_exception or self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise PermissionDenied(self.permission_denied_message)
    return redirect_to_login(...)
```

Where `PermissionDenied` class as simple as that:

```
class PermissionDenied(Exception):
    """The user did not have permission to do that"""
    pass
```